# Google Cloud VM additional IP adress same subnet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I have some VMs in Google Cloud Platform.

**Objective**

Configure multiple internal IP addresses (static), for each VM, belonging to same subnet. Each assigned IP could then be used by different services installed inside VMs.

**Environment Description**

1. No. 1 VPC network | **Name:** vpc-net-01
2. No. 1 subnet (associated to vpc-net-01) | **Name:** vpc-net-01-sub-01. **IP class:** 172.31.6.0/24
3. No. 3 VMs (Linux OS)

Basically I already know how to create and assign a static IP address for each VM (*link: [Reserving a Static Internal IP Address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address)*).

**Questions**

How can I assign, for example, 5 additional IP addresses for each VM ? I cannot use multiple NICs for each VM because I have only one VPC network and is not possible to attach multiple network interfaces to the same VPC network.

Do I have to use [Alias IP Ranges](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/alias-ip) ? But they use a "Container" concept. So, for example, for each VM I configure the primary CIDR as "Subnet range" and these as "Alias IP range":

1. VM01 - 172.31.6.8/29
2. VM02 - 172.31.6.16/29
3. VM03 - 172.31.6.24/29

Then, what I have to do ? From Do I have to configure each VM (OS I mean) by adding static IP addresses, belonging to alias IP range associated to that VM ?

Or should I use another method ? Example: enabling IP forwarding for the VM, creating a static network route, adding appropriate firewall rules, and setting additional internal IP addresses to network adapter of Windows (*link: [Set a static target internal IP address using routes](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#set_a_static_target_ip_address)*) ?

Thank you.
Luca

Answer (score 1):

I think there are different ways to accomplish what you are trying to do and I am going to tell you how I would set it up, that doesn't mean that it for sure the best solution.

Honestly I do not love multiple public IPs on the very same machine, I do not like as well to mess up with the networking configuration of an instance if I do not have to because it really easy to make mistakes and the troubleshooting is paintful.

Since you are using Google Cloud Platform I think that the easiest way to proceed is to have an instance having merely a private IP offering the different services on different ports with different frontends (Google Cloud [LoadBalancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) HTTP(s), TCP, UDP, ecc) each one with a different public IP.

[Here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-load-balancers/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) you can find a step to step guide leading you to the implementation.

I know that your question was actually "how can I have multiple public IP on the same instance", my answer is "you do not need them, so it easier to set up a different configuration".

Comment: Hello GalloCedrone,
I'm sorry but I don't need to have multiple PUBLIC IP address, but, instead, multiple PRIVATE IP address.

Comment: There are internal LoadBalancer as well https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/internal/

Answer (score 0):

yes, you should use alias IP ranges.
those will transparenly map to you compute system without the need to add them as a static ip in the system itself. Of course, if you want to run different services on the same system with a specific IP (like multiple websites over same port but on different IP's) then you'll need to add the tips to the system. On a Windows machine meaning, you need to skip DHCP and enter IP manually and then adding the additional ones in the nic settings.
not such a clean setup, but manageable in a "static" environment.